# Jitsi server in Docker enviroment conectivity from mobile client

Tags: docker, jitsi

I have installed jitsi environment in Docker. The docker-compose command creates the 4 containers and everything seems to work fine. I can even make a conference between several members, in my local network, every member points its web browser to docker host successfully.

I have another Jitsi environment, installed through apt-get package and it works fine as well. Great job Jitsiers.

The thing here is that my official mobile jitsi clients cannot join any conversation in the Docker Jitsi server, but they can do it smoothly in jitsi local installed through apt-get.

Do you have any idea about what's going on? I think its an OOBox installation.
Thanks in advance, Daniel.

Comment: After giving 10³ rounds we have realised that you can not test in a local network with an Ip and mobile clients, because the mobile is giving an exception due to certificate. So we created a domain pointing to docker host, add a certificate to it and then it seems that we can start the meeting. The thing is that before it didn't even start. Althought I can not connect on the chat

Comment: Moving on, with this issue, me have moved to a bigger server, created a certificate and opened for pots 8000, and 8443. In web environment everything seems to work right. Its posible that for mobile we need port 10000 open?